# Linq GroupBy expression raises AnonymousType exception

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a query that returns an `IEnumerable` that I use to display a table of values.

I would like to group the tables (using a `<H3/>` element) by the model's `DateTime` field (`StartTime`).

I altered the model to use the appropriate generic:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, FooViewModel>> routes;
```

I populate the model via a `FromSQL` query:

```
        routes = (IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, FooViewModel>>)await _context.FooViewModels
            .FromSql(@"SELECT  ..."
            )
            .GroupBy(r => new { r.StartTime.Date })
            .ToListAsync();
```

While the code passes design-time muster, I get an error at run time:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[<>f__AnonymousType5`1[System.DateTime],FooViewModel]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.DateTime,FooViewModel]]'.
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Do your group without the anonymous type `.GroupBy(r =>  r.StartTime.Date )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error is trying to tell you, you can't pass an anonymous type as a `DateTime`.

Since your view accepts a grouping of `DateTime`s, you need to pass a `DateTime` lambda to `GroupBy()` so that it has the same type.